# Is there a difference between typical spin-spin interaction and Fermi contact interaction from a mathematical point of view?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, atomic-physics

The reason for this question is that I have a paper that describes some interaction using the [Fermi contact interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_contact_interaction) in a classical form. I would like to study the same problem using quantum mechanics, in which I'm quite familiar with [Spin-Spin coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling).

Looking at both, Fermi interaction is proportional to the product of two magnetic moments, $\left< \mu_1 \cdot \mu_2 \right>$, which is proportional to spin. And Spin-Spin interaction is proportional to the term $S_1 \cdot S_2$.

So is there really any difference or is Fermi contact interaction a manifestation of spin-spin interactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are essentially the same thing, although spin-spin interaction refers to coupling of the spins of electrons in an atom with each other, due to their intrinsic magnetic momenta (as opposed to orbital magnetic momenta).

The Fermi contact interaction is that of the electron magnetic moment in the nuclear magnetic field (or vice versa).

In all these cases we're talking about the magnetic dipole-dipole interaction, and the dot product of the magnetic momenta arises from the potential energy of one magnetic moment in the field of the other. In all cases the "quantum form", as you might call it, is best for the description, although the physical origin is the same as in classical electrodynamics.